# Centered page numbers although set "twoside" option

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, double-sided, article

Using `article` class and the `twoside` option still gives me the page numbers in the center of the page. Isn't the `twoside` option supposed to put the page numbers on the left in even pages and on the right in odd pages?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,titlepage,12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}

\usepackage{xgreek}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Didot}

\title{Fuzzy Control}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\begin{abstract}
That's it!
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\include{intro}
\include{outro}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the standard document classes there are four predefined page styles; the following is a quote taken directly from the `fancyhdr` package documentation:

[image]

The default behaviour for the standard `article`, `report` or `book` document classes is to use the `plain` page style, so simply using the `twoside` class option won't give you the desired position for the page number.

If you want to change the default page style, you can use `\pagestyle{headings}`, or `\pagestyle{myheadings}` (and perhaps supply information for the header). Both options will give you, with the `twoside` option, headers containing the page numbers to the right on odd-numbered pages, and to the left on even-numbered pages.

If further customization is required, use a package such as [titleps](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) or [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to define your own page style. In any case, you will have to "activate" the page style by using the `\pagestyle` command.

A little example using `titleps` to define a new page style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,titlepage,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead[a][b][c]{left}{center}{right}
  \setfoot[a][b][c]{left}{center}{right}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

test\clearpage test

\end{document}
```

A more realistic example: no footer, header for even-numbered pages: page number to the left, section number and title to the right; header for odd-numbered pages: subsection title to the left, page number to the right; all information with `\small` font size:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\newpagestyle{mystyle}[\small]{
  \sethead[\thepage][][\thesection~\sectiontitle]{\subsectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```